# How to copy hosts file to windows guest OS in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have used [xdissent/ievms](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) to set up several Windows guest OSs in VirtualBox on my Mac.

I want to add entries to each Windows VM's `hosts` file.  I can successfully copy the `hosts` file from a Windows guest OS to my Mac like this:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "IE9 - Win7" copyfrom "C:\\Windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts" ~/Desktop/hosts --username IEUser --password Passw0rd\!
```

On my Mac I can also successfully add entries to the copied file using `echo -e "blah blah\r\n" >> hosts`.

However I haven't been able to copy the modified file back to the correct location on the Windows guest OS.  I can copy it to the Windows desktop but if I try to copy it to the correct folder I get:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "IE9 - Win7" copyto ~/Desktop/hosts "C:\\Windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"    --username IEUser --password Passw0rd\!  --verbose
Opening guest session as user 'IEUser' ...
Waiting for guest session to start ...
Guest session (ID 1) has been started
Copying from host to guest ...
Directory "." already exists
Source: /Users/andy/Desktop/hosts
Copying "/Users/andy/Desktop/hosts" to "./C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" ...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Copying file "/Users/andy/Desktop/hosts" failed with status 500, exit code 1.
VBoxManage: error: Error processing "/Users/andy/Desktop/hosts", rc=VERR_GENERAL_FAILURE
Closing guest session ...
```

Next I tried moving the file I successfully copied to the Windows desktop to the correct folder:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "IE9 - Win7" mv "/Documents and Settings/IEUser/Desktop/hosts" "/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts2"  --username IEUser --password Passw0rd\!  --verbose
Opening guest session as user 'IEUser' ...
Waiting for guest session to start ...
Guest session (ID 1) has been started
Renaming 1 entry ...
Renaming file "/Documents and Settings/IEUser/Desktop/hosts" to "/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts2" ...
VBoxManage: error: Renaming guest file failed: VERR_ACCESS_DENIED
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component GuestSession, interface IGuestSession, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FileRename(Bstr(strCurSource).raw(), Bstr(strCurDest).raw(), ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aRenameFlags))" at line 3015 of file VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp
Warning: Not all sources were renamed
Closing guest session ...
```

The clue seems to be `VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`, i.e. a permissions problem.

The `IEUser` user is set up as an Administrator so I don't understand why it can't write to the `etc` directory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBoxManage guestcontrol` is not always easy to use. If you use ievms boxes you can use the cli utility `ievmsrb` provided by the gem [ievms-ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/ievms-ruby/). To copy a file to a guest machine with ievmsrb enter:

```
$ ievmsrb copy_to_as_adm "IE9 - Win7" ~/Desktop/hosts 'C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts'
```

Because `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts` is only writable by Administrators you must use the `copy_to_as_adm` command.

Check if it was copied successfully with

```
ievmsrb cat "IE9 - Win7"  'C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts'
```

Comment: I just tried your gem (18 months later...) – it's fantastic.  It solved my problem straightaway.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For copying **into** a virtual machine you should use **copyto** instead of copyfrom.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify the complete destination path and it will be placed in the c:\windows\system32 folder (assuming you connect as Administrator).

Then after that you can use the "ren" subcommand to move the file into the 'drivers\etc\hosts' (assume you remove the original first).

## Example:

VBoxManage guestcontrol "$inputVMID" cp "$tFile" 'hosts.new' --username Administrator --password *** --verbose

followed by:

## remove the original file

VBoxManage guestcontrol "$inputVMID" rm 'drivers\etc\hosts' --username Administrator --password ** --verbose

and finally

## rename the new hosts file

VBoxManage guestcontrol "$inputVMID" ren 'hosts.new' 'drivers\etc\hosts' --username Administrator --password * --verbose

HTH